# Kivy Widget, Starting Function

Tags: python, widget, kivy

```
from random import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line

class MyPaintWidget(Widget):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        color = (random(), random(), random())
        with self.canvas:
            Color(*color)
            d = 30.
            Ellipse(pos=(50 - d / 2, 50 - d / 2), size=(d, d))
            Ellipse(pos=((100) - d / 2, 50 - d / 2), size=(d, d))
            Ellipse(pos=((100) - d / 2, (100) - d / 2), size=(d, d))
            Ellipse(pos=(50 - d / 2, (100) - d / 2), size=(d, d))



class MyPaintApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyPaintWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

Modification of the paint program from a tutorial.

What I want is to change it so that the 4 dots will be there at the start of the program rather than when clicked. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Those dots are displayed by your `on_touch_down` function, which is automatically triggered when you click, so that is the reason why there is nothing display until you click. You can easily fix it by modifying your `MyPaintWidget` to this:

```
class MyPaintWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyPaintWidget, self).__init__()
        self.dots()

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.dots()

    def dots(self):
        color = (random(), random(), random())
        with self.canvas:
            Color(*color)
            d = 30.
            Ellipse(pos=(50 - d / 2, 50 - d / 2), size=(d, d))
            Ellipse(pos=((100) - d / 2, 50 - d / 2), size=(d, d))
            Ellipse(pos=((100) - d / 2, (100) - d / 2), size=(d, d))
            Ellipse(pos=(50 - d / 2, (100) - d / 2), size=(d, d))
```